# how to sync list from firestore collection realtime (component + service)

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, angular-services

I'm trying to present firestore collection as list in html page, first I create Observable on the list from my component and it worked fine but I realize that it should be in the service, I changed my code to this:

in service constructor:

```
this.tenantCollection = this.angularFirestore.collection('landlord').doc(this.user.uid).collection("tenants", ref => {
              return ref.orderBy('name')})
this.tenantsList = this.tenantCollection.valueChanges();
```

and function to return this Observable (also in the service):

```
getTenants(){
  return this.tenantsList;
}
```

the component:

```
constructor(private landlordService: LandlordService, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private angularFirestore: AngularFirestore, private auth: AuthService) {
   this.auth.user.subscribe(user => {
        if (user) {
            this.user = user;              
    this.landlordService.getTenants().subscribe(tenanes => {
        this.tenants = tenanes;
        console.log(this.tenants);
    });
        }
    });
```

html:

```
<app-tenant-item *ngFor="let t of tenants | async; let i= index" [tenant]="t" [index]="i">
    </app-tenant-item>
```

This list is always empty although there are values in this way firestore, (I put the subscription in the constructor that ngOnInit activated before I have the user).

How can I fix it and get the changes real time?

Comment: Remove the `async` pipe from the `ngFor`. Will it work?

Comment: Thank you very very much! works great

Comment: Great to hear that. Actually, it's recommended not to subscribe at all. I added an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the issue is that you manually subscribe to your observable returned by the `landlordService.getTenants` method. So now, the `tenants` variable holds raw data, not an observable.

You need to either remove the `async` pipe:

```
<app-tenant-item *ngFor="let t of tenants; let i= index" [tenant]="t" [index]="i">
</app-tenant-item>
```

or assign the `tenants` variable to the observable the `landlordService.getTenants` method returns and **keep** the `async` pipe in your template:

```
this.tenants = this.landlordService.getTenants();
```

The second approach is preferred because you won't need to unsubscribe manually to avoid memory leaks. More info on this: https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-question-rxjs-subscribe-vs-async-pipe-in-component-templates-c956c8c0c794 .